# Scroll Direction

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrolltop

Trying to make div move with mousescroll in opposite direction of scroll from top right to bottom left hand corner.

Right now its going from bottom left to top right

```
#block {
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
left: 100px;



<script>
$(function(){
    var lastScrollYPos = 0;
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $block = $('#block'),
            // retrieves the top and left coordinates
            position = $block.offset(),
            // X and Y factors allows to change the diagonal movement direction and
            // degree. Negative values inverts the direction.
            factorX = 1,
            factorY = 1,
            // retrieves current vertical scrolling position and calculate the
            // relative offset
            scrollYPos = $this.scrollTop(),
            offset = Math.abs(scrollYPos - lastScrollYPos),
            // mouse wheel delta is inverted respect to the direction, so we need to
            // normalize it against the direction
            direction = scrollYPos > lastScrollYPos ? -1 : 1,
            // calculates the new position. NOTE: if integers only are used for factors,
            // then `Math.floor()` isn't required.
            newTop = position.top + Math.floor(direction * offset * factorY),
            newLeft = position.left - Math.floor(direction * offset * factorX);

        // moves the block
        $block.offset({ top: newTop, left: newLeft });
        lastScrollYPos = scrollYPos;
    });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: It seems like it's working to me, do you mean you want it to scroll from the top right to the bottom left when you scroll UP?

Comment: Making it scroll form top right to bottom left as you scroll down the page. Iv just added the css

Comment: It seems to me like setting the top and left that way makes it act weird. Maybe try positioning the div non-absolutely, that way scrolling up and down works as normal, and you only really need to keep track of left/right.

Comment: Sorry, on my personal machine I have my preferences "scroll direction" as off. Im looking for the effect, as you scroll the div enters the screen diagonally from top right to bottom left

Answer (score 0):

I've flipped it around, by inverting the direction (as is commented) and then adding the last Y position instead of subtracting it (i've commented that)

```js
$(function() {
  var lastScrollYPos = 0;
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $block = $('#block'),
      // retrieves the top and left coordinates
      position = $block.offset(),
      // X and Y factors allows to change the diagonal movement direction and
      // degree. Negative values inverts the direction.
      factorX = -1,
      factorY = -1,
      // retrieves current vertical scrolling position and calculate the
      // relative offset
      scrollYPos = $this.scrollTop(),
      // ---- Flip around the offset calculation
      offset = Math.abs(scrollYPos + lastScrollYPos),
      // mouse wheel delta is inverted respect to the direction, so we need to
      // normalize it against the direction
      direction = scrollYPos > lastScrollYPos ? -1 : 1,
      // calculates the new position. NOTE: if integers only are used for factors,
      // then `Math.floor()` isn't required.
      newTop = position.top + Math.floor(direction * offset * factorY),
      newLeft = position.left - Math.floor(direction * offset * factorX);

    // moves the block
    $block.offset({
      top: newTop,
      left: newLeft
    });
    lastScrollYPos = scrollYPos;
  });
});
```

```css
.body {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 1000px;
}

#block {
  height: 750px;
  width: 500px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: -700px;
  left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div id="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im trying to get it in reverse direction

Comment: so block enters screen at top right corner and leaves in bottom left. sorry for the confusion :/

Comment: No problem I've made an attempt there, should be enough to get you started